# Very simple large page: 1) scrollable (x and y), 2) arbitrary <div> positioning

Tags: jquery, html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I want to make a **very simple**, minimalist page, as summarized in the image.

1. Page usually larger than viewport: so scrollable in x and y.
2. Place  at arbitrary absolute positions.

Bonus: navbar on top to load other pages (bootstrap?)

[image: Desired layout]

I'm a backend Java programmer, with just a little of Angular, javascript, jQuery... Bootstrap can do nice nav bars, but can I then do absolute positioning?

The code below positions the divs, but I cannot scroll. Just fixing that would be great. The same code is also at https://jsfiddle.net/y1f2koj6/1/ .

```
<!DOCTYPE html><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
  <div style="position: fixed; left: 35px; top:  200px; width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">(Test-middle)</div>
  <div style="position: fixed; left: 35px; top: 1500px; width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll;">(Test-end)</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: since you are new, a recommendation.Go to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) and try recreating the problem there. It would be simple for others to take a look at the problem and solve it.

Comment: Good idea, @YogeshPatil. I added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this using classic position relative absolute combo.

First i encapsulated the divs in a single container div with position: absolute.
Then i updated the fixed position div to position: relative ( relative to the container)

```
<div style="position: absolute;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 35px; top:  200px; width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid red;">
      (Test-middle)
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative; left: 535px; top: 1500px; width: 400px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid blue;">
      (Test-end)
    </div>  
</div>
```

Working fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/0mncf9zq/

Comment: Fabulous! Thank you so much.